# How to edit configured headers in karate framework

Tags: karate

In my framework I have headers.js file. I am calling that js file on background of every feature file using the command `* configure headers = read('headers.js')`. This working as expected, some scenarios I need to change the 'client-id' value. For example headers.js has a client-id=xyz, I need to change client-id=abc for couple of scenarios rest all are using client-id as xyz (my headers have 20 different values, I don't want to write that in require feature files) Is there any way to modify one value from the headers.js file and use that as a header for the request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The configured headers always is the last to be applied. So the best solution for you is to create a second `headers-xyz.js` and for only those needed scenarios do `* configure headers = read('headers-xyz.js')`.

It is up to you to refactor the js code so that you can re-use most of it. For example, this might work:

```
   function() {
     var fun = karate.read('headers.js');
     var res = fun();
     res['client-id'] = 'xyz';
     return res;
   }
```

Comment: Thanks Peter it is useful.

Comment: Hey peter if I want to remove one header value from the json (For example if I want to remove 'client-id' from header). What to do?

Comment: @user9065498 you can use normal JS `delete res['client-id'];` should work in the above example.